# nodejs stream wait until I recieve my URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloudinary

I use cloudinary api to upload my files with stream. The problem is if I upload my image I recieve the URL to late. My backend sends back if I stream a empty URL and after 2-3 seconds I get in console log my uploaded URL. how can I wait until I have my uploaded URL (secure_url)

```
        if(getExtensionFromMime === 'jpeg') {
          imgSharp = await sharp(blobToBuffer).jpeg({quality: 90}).toBuffer();
        } else {
          imgSharp = await sharp(blobToBuffer).png({quality: 90}).toBuffer();
        }

        const stream = cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload_stream(
          { folder: "uploads" },
          (error, result) => {
            if (error) return console.error(error);
            console.log(result?.secure_url);
             return result?.secure_url;
          }
        );

        bufferToStream(imgSharp).pipe(stream);
  
      }
 
      return res.json(secureURLS);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response from the upload request to Cloudinary hasn't come through by the time you render the JSON response. You could wrap it in a Promise and wait for it to resolve before rendering your response.

```
// ... other code

if(getExtensionFromMime === 'jpeg') {
    imgSharp = await sharp(blobToBuffer).jpeg({quality: 90}).toBuffer();
} else {
    imgSharp = await sharp(blobToBuffer).png({quality: 90}).toBuffer();
}


function uploadStreamToCloudinary(buffer) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    cloudinary.v2.uploader
      .upload_stream(
        {
          folder: "uploads"
        },
        (error, result) => {
          if (error) {
            return reject(error);
          }
          resolve(result);
        }
      )
      .end(buffer);
  });
}

const result = await uploadStreamToCloudinary(imgSharp);

return res.json(result); // or extract only the `result?.secure_url;`
```